# Tomcat 7 log files differences

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

There are 3 types of log files generated in tomcat7 logs directory:

- catalina.[date].out|log
- localhost.[date].out|txt
- localhost_access_log.[date].txt

I have some theories based on the content of the files, but I would like to get reliable answer. I would like to know:

- Why there are multiple file extensions (out,log,txt)
- What each file contains and what is the difference beetween them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-by-one:

#### `catalina.out`

This is the content of the output to STDOUT of the Tomcat process.

#### `localhost_access_log.txt`

This is the output from the [`AccessLogValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve), as (most likely) configured in your `server.xml`.

#### `catalina.log`

This is the ouput from Tomcat's [logging framework](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html). This is configured in `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties`.

#### Mystery files

Your other files, `localhost.out|txt` come from one of these sources. I suspect that `localhost.txt` might come from a misconfigured `AccessLogValve`, which outputs to `localhost.txt` before rotating to `localhost_access_log.[date].txt`.

It could also be that you have a misconfigured `logging.properties` that outputs logs from the `localhost` `Host` to a `txt` file rather than a `log` file.